# Setting an application to launch on a filetype in a specific folder?

Tags: fedora, application, nemo

I am currently using Fedora 26 with Cinnamon 3.4.6. Using Nemo as my default file manager.

I have a folder for Retro Arcade games, and some file types are a `.bin`. I want to change it to where anything outside the folder can be the default, but in this folder for it to change to `mednafen`.

So, for example. Running the `.bin` file extension by default would do this:
[image]

But running it in a certain folder would start `mednafen '/.../Adventures of Batman and Robin, The (E).bin'` and launch the file in mednafen for emulation.

Is this possible at all? Is there a script I can do that can easily do this? Any command or package that allows this to happen?

I am not big on scripting. Only just beginning to program python.

I don't want to "Choose a Program" for the `.bin` file extension just incase I need it in the future to open to another program by default.